# Hyperlinks not working on mobile

Tags: jquery

We have a website using Sharepoint 2013 and I'm running into an odd error.  We have a pretty simple jQuery dropDown that displays a list of records when clicked.  Works fine viewed in full screen but if I try to click them in mobile, or using Chrome Dev tools set to emulate a mobile device I get the following:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxxxx.com/Programs/056607/pages/projectstatus.aspx' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
'http://xxxxx.com/pages/Error.aspx?AccessDenied'. This 
request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Having a hard time debugging this.  I can't reproduce the issue in our DEV environments but from a purely speculative viewpoint I can't figure out what about having it just set to a smaller screen would produce this result.

Comment: look for all hard-coded http and change them to https, like the error message says, you are trying to serve the mobile page over https but there is a non https script on the page

Comment: I don't have access to some of the stuff that holds the "http", working on getting that now, but in the meantime I'm trying to figure out what difference just loading the page on a smaller screen makes.

Comment: Sounds like you are using adaptive templates so it sounds like your mobile is redirecting to use secure pages only in the live environment

Comment: It looks like there is a Google Analytics script in there that I didn't know about.  I only have access to some of the code, so hopefully removing this will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your style sheets and script links. Make sure they are server over `https`. Best thing to do is [use // as the scheme](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

**Example**

```
<img src="//domain.com/img/logo.png">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
```